# composer update issue laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, centos, composer-php, centos7

update composer last night my code working perfectly on xampp local pc but when i upload on server centos 7 only blank page appear and log error. code perfectly working before update composer update on server centos 7. please give any suggestion.

```
[Mon Oct 13 04:34:00.611556 2014] [:error] [pid 26259] [client 125.209.84.194:2710] PHP Warning:  require(/home/test/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/test/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 58

[Mon Oct 13 04:34:00.611746 2014] [:error] [pid 26259] [client 125.209.84.194:2710] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/test/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php' (include_path='/home/test/public_html/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/test/public_html/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 58
```

Comment: Delete the vendor folder on the server and run `composer install` again

Answer (score 0):

Delete vender folder and composer.lock file

Now run composer install and upload complete code on server

Comment: You should *not* have deleted the `composer.lock` file - now when you run the `composer install` it will be the equilivant of `composer update` and pull in the latest copies of all packages - which might not match your development environment